# How can i interpolate ivars into Rails i18n strings during validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, interpolation

Suppose I have a model class like this:

```
class Shoebox < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_inclusion_of :description, :in => ["small", "medium"],
    :message => I18n.t("activerecord.errors.models.shoebox.with_name",
                     :name => name)
end
```

And some yaml:

```
en:
 activerecord:
  errors:
   models:
    shoebox:
     with_name: "the description of %{name} is not in the approved list"
```

And I create a new Shoebox:

```
   s = Shoebox.new(:description => "large", :name => "Bob")
   s.valid?
```

But when I look at the error (s.errors.first.message), I see:

> "the description of Shoebox is not in
>   the approved list"

and not:

> "the description of Bob is not in the
>   approved list"

I've tried `:name => name`, `:name => :name`, `:name => lambda{name}`, `:name => lambda{:name}`.

I've tried creating a helper method

```
 def shoebox_name
   name
 end
```

And passing `:name => shoebox_name`, `:name => :shoebox_name`, `:name => lambda{shoebox_name}` and `:name => lambda {:shoebox_name}`.

How can I get the ivar value for name to be interpolated into the string?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the message option in the validation, and change your yaml to be:

```
en:
 activerecord:
  errors:
   models:
    shoebox:
     description:
       inclusion: "the description of %{name} is not in the approved list"
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models for more details

Comment: The %{name} needs to be a %{value}

Answer (score -1):

You can use a custom validation method to achieve what you are trying to do. All the columns are available in the custom validator:

```
validate :description_in

def description_in
  if !(["small", "medium"].include?(description))
    errors.add(:base, "The description of #{name} is not in the approved list")
  end
end
```

PS: After a lot of googling around, I realized that it was much easier to implement a custom validator than search around.

Comment: probably because i18n was not used?